# Restricting website access with 3G modem (tried Windows SteadyState)

Tags: internet-explorer, 3g, ip-restrictions

Is it possible to restrict the allowed websites to a few pre-specified sites?

I already tried restricting with Windows Steadystate but it didn't restrict anything.

I also tried change the hosts file to 'hardcode ip' addresses and then setting fake DNS servers for the 3g modem. The DNS settings would not stick to the 3g modem.

I also tried setting a false proxy address in Internet Explorer but the 3g modem didn't honor the Internet Explorer settings.

Anyone have any ideas how to tame this USB 3g modem BEAST?